# Controller Property is null in file uploader Post Action

Tags: asp.net-mvc, upload, controller, asp.net-mvc-4

i use one controller for upload files (`UploadImageController` with action `AddFiles` returned partial view)

in other controllers in view it use as: 
`@{ Html.RenderAction(MVC.Admin.UploadImage.AddFiles(new MyImageService())); }`

where MyImageService is class with informaion about upload path, image sazes and other (`MyImageService : IImageService`)

in `UploadImageController` i add property `IImageService _imageService { get; set; }`
and `AddFiles` action:

```
public virtual PartialViewResult AddFiles(IImageService service)
{
    _imageService = service;
    return PartialView();
}
```

when i try upload files in action

```
[HttpPost]
public virtual ActionResult UploadFiles()
{...}
```

my property `_imageService == null`, why and how i can change it?

Answer (score 0):

It is recommended to initialize the Controller's field [in the Constructor](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vs2010trainingcourse_aspnetmvcdependencyinjection_topic2) (i.e. before the Action call):

```
private IImageService _imageService;
public UploadImageController(IImageService service) {
    _imageService = service;
}
```

Comment: i try. is the first thing I did, all the same '_imageService == null'

Comment: when i  call action 'AddFiles' constructor is executed, but when called 'UploadFiles()' my imageService is null...currently i add enum 'ServiceTypa' as Model for uploader view, and then use model as parameter for 'UploadFiles(ServiceType type)'